# Write to gl_FragDepth. Precision?

Tags: opengl, glsl

what I'm trying to do:

1. Render each mesh of a scene in a single pass
2. Blend the result of each pass into a final image with respect to depth of each mesh.

---

I am rendering meshes with one render pass per mesh, storing color and depth in a FBO per mesh. The depth component for each mesh's FBO has 32 bits.

Finally, a screen filling quad is rendered and the color of each FBO is written to a final FBO to some `out vec4 fragColor` and the depth to `gl_FragDepth`, with `layout(depth_any) out float gl_FragDepth`. The depth func is set to `GL_LEQUAL`.

If two meshes were the same, I'd expect to see the mesh that was blended last into the scene because of `GL_LEQUAL`. But what I get is noise, some fragments of the last mesh pass the depth test, some don't.

Basically I am just copying depth values from one FBO to another and this seems to induce errors.
For accessing the depth component I tried both, binding the texture as `sampler2D` and `sampler2DShadow`.

As a test I did the following:
Instead of a full screen quad, all meshes are rendered again with depth test so that only the color values of the surviving fragments of the according FBO are written to the final FBO.
This gives the expected result in the case where two meshes are the same.

Where does that loss of precision come from, when reading from a depth component texture and writing to `gl_FragDepth`?

---

**EDIT**

Full Screen Quad Approach [image: img]

This image was produced the following way:

1. The gray colored mesh you see was rendered twice, with the same
   shaders and the same input to model view projection. No other
   uniforms affect the vertex transform. The black contour lines can be ignored.
2. Both meshes have their own FBO (FBO_A and FBO_B) with textures for output variables color and depth and a depth attachment. The depth per pixel is computed in the fragment shader and written to a 2D texture (with invariant qualifyer), in addition to the standard depth attachment.
3. In a second step a screen filling quad is rendered to FBO_final. Color values of FBO_A are written to the color output and the depth values of FBO_A are written to `gl_FragDepth`. I tried both, taking the depth values from the manually computed output and from the standard depth attachment.
4. Now some post processing is done on the color of FBO_final, but to highlight the errors lets just clear the color to white. The depth of FBO_final is not cleared.
5. The screen filling quad is rendered again, this time accessing FBO_B in the same way as in 3.

This result is shown in the image above.
The second run of the screen filling quad had some fragments not passing the depth test with `GL_LEQUAL`, which gives sight on the clear color.

Mesh Approach [image: img]

This image was generated almost in the same way as in the Full Screen Quad Approach. The only difference is in step 3. and 5. Now, instead of a quad the original mesh itself is rendered to generate the fragments for access to FBO_A and FBO_B.

That means, color is written to FBO_final by the fragment shader and the depth is written automatically by the pipeline instead of writing to `gl_FragDepth` in the fragment shader. The result is correct.

---

Actually I found the Mesh Approach to be much faster and it gives the expected results. Anyway I am still curious about why the other approach fails.

Comment: A mesh does not have ***a*** depth component. Pixels have depth components. Fragments have depth components. But meshes generate multiple fragments, and thus the "mesh" has lots of depth values.

Comment: "*If two meshes were the same,*" Are they *really* the same? Do they have the exact same binary identical vertex data? Do they run through the exact same shaders with the exact same uniform values?

Comment: The depth component for each mesh's dedicated FBO was meant. Sorry for the bad formulation.
The two meshes in my test case are the same and run with the exact same conditions as made sure with the second approach I mentioned.

Comment: Invariance has never been an (automatic) guarantee in the vertex transform pipeline (ignoring some new stuff for tessellation shaders). It's been a long time since this has caused me many problems but to this day invariance between two identical passes is not guaranteed. `GL_LEQUAL` is typically an adequate test to deal with these problems and this discussion applies mostly to people who attempt to use `GL_EQUAL` for multi-pass rendering; don't do that.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Also I assume when you say you "bound the texture as `sampler2DShadow`" you mean you bound a 2D texture with comparison enabled?

Comment: You may want to look into the `invariant` qualifier in GLSL. Not completely sure this is your problem, but it's worth checking.

Comment: see and try  http://stackoverflow.com/q/18994069/2521214